# adding stripe connect to angular 2 , typescript?

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

In an angular2 application, I want to integrate a stripe connect so that users can sell their stuff.

Do I need a `node.js` server to implement this part ? or it could be done like stripe checkout directly?

Comment: I found this YouTube clip for firebase, not sure if it will help you - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lZc2O2oUJk

Answer (score 0):

You'll always need a backend (ie: nodejs server as you mentioned) with Stripe. Wether you use Checkout or not - you get a token back and you need to process a charge against that token.

Here's a link to their documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart#elements

And here's a snippet from that documentation:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

// Token is created using Stripe.js or Checkout!
// Get the payment token submitted by the form:
var token = request.body.stripeToken; // Using Express

// Charge the user's card:
var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: "usd",
  description: "Example charge",
  source: token,
}, function(err, charge) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

Note the comment that you get the token from either Stripe.js or Checkout.

Comment: i used the checkout without a backend following to this tutorial:
http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/07/05/using-stripe-payment-with-angular-2/

i need the to set the stripe connect button on my app

Comment: Nothing in that tutorial deals with actually creating the charge. You get a token back from checkout - you still need to pass that to your server, where your private key will live, and create a charge on the account. I'm guessing you don't have a real live app charging people's credit cards?

Comment: i know the actual charge need the backend, i mean in my question how to implement the stripe connect, not the stripe checkout, i need users to sell their products

Comment: Yes you still need a backend since you'll use OAuth to have your users log in and Stripe needs a server to callback to.

Comment: any example? tutorial ?